# How to persuade Pandoc to read definition lists in GitHub Flavored Markdown?

Tags: latex, pandoc, github-flavored-markdown, kramdown

I am trying to automate conversion of a GitHub Pages site to LateX in order to produce a PDF. The Kramdown parser used by GHP understands the following definition list syntax:

```
term1
: definition1
term2
: definition 2
```

so definition lists formatted this way in Markdown show up correctly on GHP. However, Pandoc's `--from=gfm` flag does *not* understand this syntax, since it's not officially part of the GFM spec.  I have tried:

```
--from=gfm+definition_lists
```

but the `definition_lists` extension appears to be ignored with `from=gfm`. I have also tried:

```
--from=markdown+definition_lists+attribute_headers
```

but that doesn't appear to understand Kramdown-style attribute headers (which I need in order to specify section IDs, because legacy text).  Is there a way to get Pandoc to deliver the definition list behavior of Jekyll+Kramdown *and* attribute headers? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try `-f markdown_github+definition_lists`.  `markdown_github` is pandoc's legacy gfm parser.  `gfm` is the new one, which just wraps the C library and so doesn't accept all the extensions.